# load OBJ file from blob in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blob, arraybuffer

I'm trying to load an OBJ file from a blob with three js.
I've referred to [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-load-blob-objects/37970) and got STLs to load. But it's not working for OBJs.
The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: text.indexOf is not a function
    at OBJLoader.parse (OBJLoader.js:482:13)
```

Here's my code:

```
    // this gives an error
    async loadObj(blob) {
        var loader = new OBJLoader();
        const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        const geometry = loader.parse(arrayBuffer);
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({});
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
    }
   
    // this works
    async loadStl(blob) {
        const loader = new STLLoader();
        const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        const geometry = loader.parse(arrayBuffer);
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({});
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);

    }
```

Comment: The C++ tag [tag:stl] has nothing to do with stl or obj files. When you choose tags, Is it really that hard to read tag descriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loader.parse` expects a string, you are passing an array buffer. Try passing a string instead:

```js
async loadObj(blob) {
        var loader = new OBJLoader();
        const blog_string = await blob.text();
        const geometry = loader.parse(blog_string);
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({});
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
}
```

[OBJLoader.parse Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader.parse)

[OBJLoader.parse Source Code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js#L488)

[MDN Blob.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text)

Comment: It's still not working. I'm getting the error ```TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object```

Comment: On which line does this occur? Have you checked that `blob` is not null? You can do this like so: `console.assert(typeof blob != null)`

Comment: blob is not null.
the error occurs on this line: ```const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);```